# ZingChart: Cannot read property 'FA' of undefined (on any chart event)

Tags: angularjs, charts, zingchart

Roughly 20% of the time I load a page with this ZingChart on it, I get the following error when I either mouse-over or click a node on my pie ZingChart:

```
VM57:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'FA' of undefined
    at HTMLAreaElement.m.YS (eval at <anonymous> (http://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js:8:1), <anonymous>:1:439813)
    at HTMLDocument.d (eval at <anonymous> (http://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js:8:1), <anonymous>:1:89798)
```

In the minified js chrome debugger highlights this line:

```
t(p[0]-v,p[1]-u);if(r&&m.E["node-target-id"]&&m.E["node-target-id"]!==r.id){return}}if(ZC.N.R2(q.target).indexOf("zc-node-area")===-1){return}if(m.L1!=="ready"){return}if(ZC.mobile){m.A.N6(q)}var n=b(q);var o=m.AY.A
```

Other times it will behave just as expected. Refreshing the page will generally (but not every time) see the problem disappear. I'm hoping this is an issue with my implementation.

**Chart:**

```
$scope.SalesChartData = {
        type: "pie",
        id: 'chart_1',
        title: {
          textAlign: 'center',
          text: "Loading..."
        },
        "legend":{
          "border-width":1,
          "border-color":"gray",
          "border-radius":"5px",            
          "marker":{
            "type":"circle"
          },
          "toggle-action":"remove",
          "icon":{
            "line-color":"#9999ff"
          }
        },   
        "plot": {
          "animation":{
            "on-legend-toggle": true,
            "effect": 5,
            "method": 1,
            "sequence": 1,
            "speed": 0.7
          },
          "value-box": {
            "text": "$%v",
            "negation": "currency",
            "thousands-separator": ",",
            "font-color": "black",
            "placement":"in",
            "offset-r":"50%",
            "font-size":"12"            
          },
          "tooltip":{
            "text":"%t: $%v (%npv%)",
            "thousands-separator":","
          },
          "decimals": "0",
          "detach": false
        },
        series: [],
        shapes: [{
          type: 'triangle',
          backgroundColor: '#66ccff',
          size: 10,
          angle: -90,
          x: 20,
          y: 20,
          cursor: 'hand',
          id: 'backwards'
        }]
      };
```

**Init the data and display:**

```
dataService.getRevenueByRegion($scope.yr,$scope.mnth).success(function(data) {

      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $scope.SalesData.push({Revenue: [data[i].Revenue], Region: [data[i].Region], GP: [data[i].GP], Picks: [data[i].Picks], LocalBuyin: [data[i].LocalBuyin], detail: []});        
      }      

      displayRevenueByRegion();
    });
```

**displayRevenueByRegion:**

```
function displayRevenueByRegion(){

      $scope.SalesChartData.title.text="Revenue by Branch";
      $scope.SalesChartData.series=[];
      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.SalesData.length; i++) {
        $scope.SalesChartData.series.push({values: $scope.SalesData[i].Revenue, text: $scope.SalesData[i].Region, GP: $scope.SalesData[i].GP, Picks: $scope.SalesData[i].Picks, LocalBuyin: $scope.SalesData[i].LocalBuyin});
      }

      zingchart.exec('chart_1', 'destroy');

      zingchart.render({ 
        id : 'chart_1', 
        data : $scope.SalesChartData      
      });

      zingchart.exec('chart_1', 'update');

    }
```

Comment: This example does not fully explain or illustrate the problem. Despite that, there is a bug with toggling all legend items off that I found from your example. This bug was introduced in version 2.5.0. Version 2.5.1 should have a patch for this and will be out this week. I will respond with an answer when the build is ready.

Hopefully the update to the newest [angularJS directive](https://github.com/zingchart/ZingChart-AngularJS) will solve your issues.